# How to get latitude and longitude on click event with jquery-ui-map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

When using 'Google maps v3 plugin for jQuery and jQuery Mobile', how to retrieve the latitude and longitude values under the mouse pointer when clicked on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the click event listener is already added to the map inside the plugin, the event object returned, does not give the latLng value.
Adding the click event listener to the map object from my code, worked for me (found the solution by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659359/679822) answer).

```
var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
$(map).addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.latLng);
});
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the Latitude and Longitude seperatly?

Comment: Nevermind got it. it was as simple as this: `event.latLng.jb` for latitude and `event.latLng.kb` for longitude

Answer (score 2):

johansalllarsson's solution works great for me, so here is my sample of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#map').gmap();
    $($('#map').gmap('get', 'map')).dblclick(function(event) {
        alert(event.latLng);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$($('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map')).click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.latLng);
});
```

see http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geocoding.html

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesn't work. Got the following error in console: `[10:07:32.098] $("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map").click is not a function`

Comment: @johansalllarsson the link which you have attached throws a 404. Can you please update it to the functional one?