# How can I get the latitude and longitude values?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, geolocation

How can I get the latitude and longitude values.
And then show the values on the screen without map.

I use the code:

```
function success(position) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');

  if (s.className == 'success') {
    // not sure why we're hitting this twice in FF, I think it's to do with a cached result coming back    
    return;
  }

  s.innerHTML = "found you!";
  s.className = 'success';

  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';

  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"You are here! (at least within a "+position.coords.accuracy+" meter radius)"
  });
}

function error(msg) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');
  s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
  s.className = 'fail';

  // console.log(arguments);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```

Comment: http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512537/jquery-google-map-plugin-adding-event-listners/10659359#10659359

Comment: What do you mean by "without the map"?  You want to remove the map from the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the position object of your success method in order to get latitude and longitude values;

```
alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude)
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation